# Implementing google sign-in server-side-flow using devise-token-auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, google-oauth, devise-token-auth

I can't find any documentation around implementing https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow with devise-token-auth. I have Rails 5 API only app. If there isn't what are the workarounds? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Devise Token Auth docs has a section for oauth setup.  Follow the instructions here:

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#omniauth-authentication

and you'll want to use this provider:

https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2

Comment: the page he links shows java and python example; what's the ruby way ?